# Unable to dynamically set image in an ImageView inside a TableRow

Tags: android, camera, imageview, tablerow

I have this LinearLayout and inside it, there is a button and a TableLayout with no rows till now, i'll add them dynamically.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_select" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TableLayout>
```

On click of the button I want the camera to be open and the image clicked to be set on an ImageView inside a new tablerow. 
Now  here is the java snippet.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablay);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    tableRow.addView(imageView);
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
}
```

Everything goes fine but the image doesn't show up on the screen.

Comment: why you are using table layout to show a list of image, Table layout just more object instead of list view.

Comment: I saw most tutorials using this only. I am very new to android, developing my college project.

Comment: you can used dynamic listview with image.

Comment: You have to use listview, in which add item listview's adapter dataset at runtime.I will send you give a example code for implement the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
tableRow = new TableRow(this);
 imageView = new ImageView(this);

tableRow.addView(imageView,new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

---

Set Params like this, because table row accept params of type TableRow only

```
 tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: I have answered few questions about the same check one of them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732729/unable-to-dynamically-populate-a-table/15732794#15732794

Comment: @AnasAzeem Make sure that bitmap is not null

Comment: No, its not. I've checked it.

Comment: It worked!!!!

But another mess, the images are shown in the landscape view, but as I switch to portrait the images disappear.

Comment: @AnasAzeem This answer deals with current question... If anything other post it in another question..And mark this as answer by clicking the right mark beside the answer

Answer (score 0):

In the main.xml file,

```
    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/infoRow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:text="Loading Content"
                    android:id="@+id/loadingMessage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/insert"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Add New" />
    </TableRow>
```

for eg: say testItem.java

```
public class testItem extends Activity
{
    private List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>(); // Please add values to this string list.

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        int count=results.size();
        TableLayout tl=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
                          for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
                          {
                              final String str=results.get(i);
                              TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                              tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                              TextView textview = new TextView(this);
                              textview.setText(str);
                              tr.addView(textview);
                              Button buttn = new Button(this);
                              buttn.setText("DELETE");
                              buttn.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                              tr.addView(buttn);
                              tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                      LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        }

        }
}
```

Comment: you can use image instead of button and textview.. try this may be its help you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Change `tableRow.addView(imageView);`

to

`tableRow.addView(imageView,100,150);` (new width and height)